# OpenCV CV findHomography assertion error - counter => 4

Tags: opencv, homography, ransac

I'm currently finishing my evaluation-tool for interest point detectors. In the last steps I found a confusing error.

```
Mat findHomography(InputArray srcPoints, InputArray dstPoints, int method=0, double ransacReprojThreshold=3, OutputArray mask=noArray() )
```

The `srcPoints` and `dstPoints` are `vector<Points2f>` which stores the corresponding points of the matched keypoints. So far nothing special - It's like in the tutorials.

But when I use RANSAC and have a `vector<Points2f>` in range [0, ... , 4], I get an assertion error than the counter should be greater or equals four.

**Question 1:** Does the algorithm needs at least four points to describe what belongs to the current model or not and to create the consensus?

**Question 2:** Is there any documentation about this? (I took a look at the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=findhomogr#cv.FindHomography) and the [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/opencv_tutorials.pdf).)

[Please note that I already have seen this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520250/opencv-cvfindhomography-runtime-error). But there is no satisfying answer for the behaviour of RANSAC. Or should I accept that this methods needs at least four points to find the homography?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A homography cannot be computed with less than 4 pairs of points.  That is because with only 3 points there is a perspective ambiguity.  Picture a triangle

```
a


b        c
```

in image 1.  In image 2 the points have been transformed to look like this

```
a


b    c
```

The distance between b and c has been cut in half.  Unfortunately you don't know if that is because point c got closer to your or farther from you.  With a 4th point the difference becomes clear.

```
a        d


b        c
```

Here is a square in image 1

```
     d


a        


b    c
```

here d and c rotated towards you

```
a     

     d
b    c
```

and here they rotated away from you.

I don't see this requirement in the openCV documentation but if you find any resources on homography calculation you won't have to read very far before you find this requirement and a more rigorous proof of 4 points being sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

RANSAC is used to select 4 pairs of matching points in a greater set or correspondences (i.e. when `srcPoints.size() >= 4`). That's why you get an error if `srcPoints.size() <=4`.

You need at least 4 correspondences simply because a Homography matrix `H` has 8 degrees of freedom, hence 8 linear equations are required to find a solution. Since each pairs of points generates two linear equations (using x and y coordinates) you'll need a total of at least 4 correspondences.

Comment: Can you please give me a hint where I can read this equations? I only found some phrases in texts which told me "you need at least four points" but without any explanation.

Comment: Check this out: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi07/cse252a/homography_estimation/homography_estimation.pdf